# Way to make a Content Control un-editable but still deletable

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The following flags exist on Content Controls: `cannotEdit`, `cannotDelete` and `removeWhenEdited`.

`cannotDelete = true` results in a Content Control which can be edited but cannot be deleted.

`cannotEdit = true` results in a Content Control which can be neither edited nor deleted.

`removeWhenEdited = true` results in a Content Control which, upon editing, removes the Content Control while leaving the contained text.

I'm looking for a way to make a Content Control whose underlying text cannot be edited but where the entire control can be deleted somehow, perhaps by selecting the control itself and hitting delete. Does such a configuration exist?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose just set cannotEdit to true will meet your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately not: users would potentially end up with content controls which cannot be removed, and it's in a context where the control could be created by mistake so it needs to be removable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Word does not provide that option. It would need to be completely coded in the add-in and the interface for the user to choose that would also need to be part of the add-in.

My recommendation would be to assign (copy) the content control's `Range`to a point just before or after the content control, enable deletion of the content control then delete it.